# In python what does [pos for pos, word in enumerate(sentence, start=1) if word == word_positions] actually do in my code?

Tags: python, enumerate

I know this question comes off as a bit, silly, I mean, I wrote the code! This particular bit of code however I got off a website I can no longer find, and I need to do a write up on the code.

Here's the code:

```
sentence = input("Please input a sentence\n").lower().split() 
# Assigns a sentence to a variable, puts it into lower case and then splits the string into words

word_positions = input("Please input a word\n") 
# Assigns a word for the program to print its positions 

end = [pos for pos, word in enumerate(sentence, start=1) if word == word_positions]

print (end)
# prints the positions of the word
```

The results of running the code look like:

```
Please input a sentence
The cat sat on the mat
Please input a word
the
[1, 5]
```

Its just `[pos for pos, word in enumerate(sentence, start =1) if word == word positions]` that I need to know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

```
end = [pos for pos, word in enumerate(sentence, start=1) if word == word_positions]
```

enumerate will create an iterable enumerate object of tuples. I have used `list(...)` to make it clear

```
>>> list(enumerate(['a','b','c'], start=1))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

so `pos for pos,word in ... if condition`

means "given the tuple `(pos,word)`" give me the first element (i.e pos)
if the `condition` is met. In this case the condition is that the second element of the tuple `(pos,word)` must be equal to `word_positions`

As this is a list comprehention this will be carried out for every tuple in the enumerate object (i.e the pairs of number,word)

Note that `pos for (pos,word) in ... if condition` is the same and a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as

```
end = []
i = 0
while i < len(sentence):
    if sentence[i] == word_positions:
        end.append(i+1)
    i += 1
```